# You don’t have permission to save the file “Images.xcassets” in the folder "AppName"

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm working on a react native app and I keep getting this error when saving changes to the Images.xcassets file:

```
You don’t have permission to save the file “Images.xcassets” in the folder "AppName".
To view or change permissions, select the item in the Finder and choose File > Get Info.
```

I've tried to fix the permissions in finder like instructed and in terminal by navigating to the correct folder and changing permissions with this command:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 Images.xcassets
```

and (on the parent folder) I ran

```
sudo chmod -R 777 AppName
```

But I still get the error.  The only way I can see to get around it is to close xcode and reopen it.  The changes seem to be saved.  Any ideas?

Comment: It's the `AppName` permissions that need changing, not `Images.xcassets`.

Comment: This sounds like an XCode-related error, tagging with xcode or ios might help.

Comment: @trojanfoe, I tried running ```sudo chmod -R 777 .``` from the top folder and still no luck.  I even tried closing xcode and running it but still get the error.

Comment: Thanks @MartinKonicek, I updated the tags.

Comment: I closed Xcode and reopened. It worked for me!